# Do weapon proficiencies carry over on dropped weapons?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Modern Warfare 3 has this system for equipping a "Proficiency" on your weapons.  Does this proficiency "stick" with the weapon after it has been dropped?

For instance, if I pick up a downed friend's weapon, and he was using the "Kick" proficiency, will my shots with that gun carry a reduction in recoil as well?

What about if I mistakenly drop my weapon and then pick it back up?  Will I lose my proficiency?

If it is possible to transfer proficiency when picking up a dropped weapon, how can I tell the proficiency that its old owner was using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The proficiencies associated with the weapon picked up stay active while using the weapon.
Your profile does not keep weapon proficiencies that you haven't unlocked if you toss the weapon or get killed.

It's the same as if you pick up a gun you haven't unlocked... Even though it's not available to you "in profile", you get to run around with it for a bit.

Comment: Is there some way to check and see what the proficiency is once I've picked the weapon up?  I haven't noticed anything on the HUD.  How did you test this or what's your source?

Comment: When you pick a weapon up it states the weapon name and proficiencies in the lower right hand side of the screen like "UMP45 Rapid Fire".  Tested it in MW3 just now

Comment: Also, you can only have 1 proficiency per weapon. so if it had "2 attachments" the rest of the weapons details would be obviously on the weapon like a red dot site and a grenade launcher. I believe these attachments also show as icons on the right of the screen near your kill streak icons.

Comment: I don't use SMGs often, so I don't have the rapid fire proficiency on any of them yet.  Most of the other proficiency types don't modify the weapon's name.  I guess it's safe to assume that they're all transferable though, if those two are.

Comment: It will announce whatever proficiency is attached on pickup in the text area. not just rapid fire. That just happened to be what was on the weapon I picked up to test it. Unfortunately you can almost miss it, but if you switch between weapons it should re-state it.

Comment: also be sure you're not confusing a proficiency and an attachment.

Comment: Isn't rapid fire a perk on smgs? I didn't think it was a proficiency, but I don't play with SMGs much either.

Comment: Sean I think you are the one confusing proficiencies with attachments. Rapid fire is an attachment. The weapon name doesn't state the proficiency when you pick it up, so I'm not actually sure of the answer to the OP. My guess is that the proficiencies carry over, as you can pick up weapons with 2 attachments (so obviously the 'attachments' one does). Then again, you could pick up blinged weapons in MW2 without having that perk.

Comment: @SeanGallagher Do you have source for this? Also, there is no indication of a weapon proficiency on picked up weapons. Whether they DO work or not is being asked here. We might need to test this.

Comment: my source was me playing in a private game with a guest account. I made a class with less kick on a ump45 and the guest had no unlocks for the weapons. When the guest account picked up the ump45 with proficiency, the animation jumped less and the vibration was lighter in the controller. I didn't exhaustively test it with every scenario, but assume if it it's on the weapon it carries over while you've got it.

Comment: When running over a weapon, I've seen some labeled as "Custom" if they have 2 attachments, similar to how MW2 had "Bling" on the weapon. MK14 Custom as opposed to MK14 Red Dot. However it doesn't list proficiency until you pick it up.